# Problems with path difference

Tags: inkscape, path, path-effects

### Path Difference

---

[image: Image of fail]

I was trying to set the `path difference` in the second image.
According to my plans theoretically he should left the circle intact, cutting and shaping only the line

> ...but...

When I go to `path` set `difference` then it *"erase"* the line and the circle.

[image: Gif fail]

Why?

I don't know Inkscape very well, so can you describe me each step to make?
✨ **thanks for your helpful help!** ✨

<sub>Ps:
if you think this question is *useful* and *well written*, do not hesitate to put an **upvote**, *thanks*</sub>

Comment: Sorry, but we know nothing about the real structure of your objects - are they groups, combined paths, do they have effects etc... A plain  open Bezier curve subtracted from a fresh manually drawn circle takes off nothing, only the curve vanishes. You have something else there. What? Remove ALL  extras, leave only the line and the circle and show the Objects panel.

Comment: they are nothing `:)`  
I've just opened Inkscape and drew a circle and a line to try again, but the result is everytime the same: *Blank* .  
If you want I can share the screenshot but they are empty objects.

Comment: Blank result is still something else than what Inkscape 1.0 gives.

Comment: Yes it was, but with the help of @Billy it work Thank you too for supporting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the path using *Path > Stroke to Path*.  This will turn the stroke into a closed shape with a fill.

Now it should work.

Example

[image]

Comment: It works thanks so much

Are there any problems if I make the **line first** and **then the circle**?
What if I put the line in another **layer below** the circle?

Comment: @Lale Why don't you try it and see? Obviously the result will be completely different

Comment: I just did, and the result is very different, now I'm having fun with it... thanks a lot again for the clarification